# SQL inner join 3 tabelas

Tags: c#, sql, query

Boa Tarde. Estou querendo fazer um inner mas nao sai o resultado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Tabela1 = rec  Campo = chvbfj(3)      <- codigo do cliente
Tabela1 = rec  Campo = doc(3,4,5)     <- lista de codigos de itens do cliente
Tabela2 = vndB Campo = chvvnda(3,4,5) <- tem o codigo de itens do cliente  
Tabela2 = vndB Campo = chvps(1,1,2)   <- codigo da descrição  
Tabela3 = ps   Campo = chvps(1,1,2)   <- tem o codigo da descrição  
Tabela3 = ps   Campo = Desc(escova, escola, lixa) <- descricao do codigo
```

Fazendo a consulta do cliente(3) ele lista os itens(1,1,2), mas teria que aparecer a descricao do codigo(escova, escova, lixa).

```
 public DataTable PesquisaResumo(global::CamadaModelos.mdlEmpresa _mdlEmpresa)
    {
        string ConexaoAccess = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\tabela.mdb";
        OleDbConnection ConexaoDB = new OleDbConnection(ConexaoAccess);
        ConexaoDB.Open();

        string Query = "SELECT rec.chvbfj, rec.doc, vndB.chvvnda, vndB.chvps, ps.chvps, ps.Dsc FROM rec INNER JOIN vndB on vndB.chvvnda = rec.doc INNER JOIN ps on ps.chvps = vndB.chvps WHERE rec.chvbfj = @id";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, ConexaoDB);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbParameter pmtID = cmd.CreateParameter();
        pmtID.ParameterName = "@id";
        pmtID.DbType = DbType.String;
        pmtID.Value = _mdlEmpresa.ID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtID); 

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable empresas = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(empresas);
        ConexaoDB.Close();
        return empresas;
    }
```

Comment: Como está sua query atual?

Comment: select chvbfj, doc from rec where chvbfj=@id

Comment: Este link pode lhe ser útil: https://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-joins-em-sql/1071

Comment: na sua sql TA ASSIM `vndB.chvps, ps.chvps,` não pode ter dois nomes repetidos tira 1 deles

Comment: tirando qualquer um ou os dois da erro. (operador faltando)

Comment: então eu vou mudar a SQL pera ae

Comment: tente essa: `SELECT rec.chvbfj, rec.doc, vndB.chvvnda, vndB.chvps, ps.Desc FROM vndB 
       INNER JOIN rec ON vndB.chvvnda = rec.doc
       INNER JOIN ps ON vndB.chvps = ps.chvps
WHERE rec.chvbfj = 3`

Comment: 'Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta 'vndB.chvvnda = rec.doc INNER JOIN ps ON vndB.chvps = ps.chvps'.'

Comment: Seguinte Thiago o erro é na tabelas, não tem como a gente testar o jeito de fazer é assim cara não tem por onde, isso pode ser dados misturados, isso pode ser tanta coisa, é um problema local.

Comment: Parece que você está utilizando o Microsoft Access. Creio que ele exige que você coloque parênteses quando utiliza múltiplos join.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  a.chvbfj, b.chvvnda, c.Desc  from rec a
inner join vndB b on b.chvvnda = a.doc
inner join ps c on c.chvps = b.chvps
WHERE a.chvbfj = '3'
```

Comment: : 'Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta 'b.chvvnda = a.doc left join ps c on c.chvps = b.chvps'.'

Comment: Cara, desculpa estar tão enrolado...Estou sem SQL aqui pra montar e ver o problema real...Tente mais uma vez, por favor.

Comment: Tente tambem tirar o inner, e colocar simplesmente join

Comment: : 'Erro de sintaxe na cláusula FROM.'
erro

Comment: O nome das tabelas que você tem está exatamente igual no exemplo exposto? campos...tudo?

Comment: esta errado o c.Desc, certo c.Dsc

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM Tabela1
INNER JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela2 .id = Tabela1.id
INNER JOIN Tabela3 ON Tabela3 = Tabela1 .id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.Desc FROM rec A
JOIN vndB B on B.chvvnda = A.doc
JOIN ps C ON C.chvps = B.chvps
```

Após isso busque os dados que quiser com as condições que quiser.

Comment: 'Erro de sintaxe na cláusula FROM.'

Comment: Tenta de novo, arrumei o nome da tabela ps

Comment: : 'Erro de sintaxe na cláusula FROM.'
mesmo erro

Comment: Alterei novamente, verifique o nome das tabelas se estão iguais a que você tem.

Comment: : 'Erro de sintaxe na cláusula FROM.'
voce coloca no select C.Dsc FROM rec A ---  mas C.Dsc eh da tabela ps

Comment: errado=C.Desc Correto=C.Dsc